# Dynamic textarea adds content inside it automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is

```
$(add_button_exp).click(function(e){ 
      //on add input button click
      e.preventDefault();
      $(wrapper_exp).before('<table><tr><td><textarea spellcheck="true" class="form-control grammer_check" name="exp_lessons[]" id="exp_lessons'+exp+'" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><div class="grammer_Suggetion help-inline"></div></td></tr></table>');
)};
```

But I'm getting
[content inside the text area is not actually coded inside it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpRWg.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: witch element in selector `wrapper_exp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it
 Replace **.before()** to **.text()**

```
$(add_button_exp).click(function(e){ 
      //on add input button click
      e.preventDefault();
      $(wrapper_exp).before('<table><tr><td><textarea spellcheck="true" class="form-control grammer_check" name="exp_lessons[]" id="exp_lessons'+exp+'" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><div class="grammer_Suggetion help-inline"></div></td></tr></table>');
)};
```